# Flutter, Using a 'Skip For Now' button to skip Login/Register via Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I created a `Login` and `Register` page and it will redirect to `Home` page when there is an instance of `user`. At the `Login` screen, i want to add a "Skip For Now" button where users will not need to have an account to try out the app. Currently I am using `signinAnonymously()` for this action. Is there any pros and cons for this method? Are there any other methods I can use?

Comment: no there is no cons of using anynomous login in firebase

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is fairly idiomatic and the exact use-case that anonymous authentication was made for.